# Hex string to ASCII conversion and ASCII to Hex conversion issue

Tags: c#, hex, ascii

I have write two methods to convert Hex string to ASCII and ASCII string to Hex string. But when I compare the two strings it I getting two difference Hex strings.

Eg:
Hex string = 6220000008a01000

I convert this string to ASCII using below method

```
public static string ConvertHex(string hexString)
{
    try
    {
        string ascii = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string hs = string.Empty;

            hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
            ulong decval = Convert.ToUInt64(hs, 16);
            long deccc = Convert.ToInt64(hs, 16);
            char character = Convert.ToChar(deccc);
            ascii += character;

        }

        return ascii;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

and I convert that ASCII value back to hex string using below method

```
public string ASCIItoHex(string Value)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] inputByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Value);

    foreach (byte b in inputByte)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("{0:x2}", b));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

But as the final hex string I get below string.

Hex string = 6220000008c2a01000

Can anyone help me to figure it out what happen in there?

Comment: You're converting to hex an UTF8 encoded string. You're converting back to _plain_ string reading byte by byte assuming stream is...ASCII. It's not. Some characters in UTF8 string may be more than one byte.

Comment: Indeed, any binary data with 0xa0 in is *not* ASCII... (You're actually converting it using ISO-8859-1 at the moment, which still isn't the same as UTF-8.)

Comment: First I convert hex in to ASCII. When I convert the same ASCII value back to the hex It shows different values.

Comment: can anyone help me out to get the correct ASCII value from the hex string.

Comment: @soft009 UTF8 is not ASCII (even _assuming_ you consider ASCII as 8 bit). But point is: what are you trying to do? Convert hex to...hex again? Try to explain with an example of _input string, converted string, output string_ what you want to get.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti example of the hex string is in the question. But I cannot type the ASCII values. It's some thing like that (b \0\0\0 \0). I use this for the ISO 8583 message bit map.

Answer (score 0):

You try to represent two characters of a hex string (like "FF") as a single `char`. That does not work.

Your "hexString" is already the string representation of your hex number.

Comment: I need two characters of hex string as a single ASCII characters
62 - b
20 - space 
etc..